# Malloc failed upon git pull

Tags: git, pull

I get this error trying to git pull:

```
$git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 91, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79/79), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 2445656885 bytes)
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

How can I resolve this?

I have tried setting some memory limits in the `.gitconfig`, but it did not help:

```
[pack]
    threads = 1
    deltaCacheSize = 128m
    packSizeLimit = 128m
    windowMemory = 128m
[core]
    packedGitLimit = 128m
    packedGitWindowSize = 128m
```

Answer (score 0):

2445656885 is approx 2.5 GB. A quite unusually large number, I am not sure if malloc even allowed to request this much. May be a sign of a software bug.Check your git installation.

Comment: Well I have this one binary file which is quite big. Git allowed a push and pull on a 64bit system. Now I pulled from a 32bit system, could that be it?

Comment: Yes. This could be the reason.

Comment: Is there a way to tell git to operate on disk space using big files?